# Simultaneous D.E. $2\frac{dx}{dt}-x+\frac{dy}{dt}-2y=0$ ; $3\frac{dx}{dt}-2x+2\frac{dy} {dt}-3y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
2\frac{dx}{dt}-x+\frac{dy}{dt}-2y=0 \tag{1}
$$
$$
3\frac{dx}{dt}-2x+2\frac{dy} {dt}-3y=0 \tag{2}
$$

If you subtract $\,(1)\cdot2 - (2)\,$
I get $\,\dfrac{dx}{dt}-y=0\,$ which does not make sense if I substitute $\,\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y\,$ in the first equation or in $(2)$.
I just get $\,-x + \dfrac{dy}{dt} = 0$. 
I get lost from here I have no idea how to solve it further.

Answer (score 1):

By differentiating what you get from subtracting, we get 
$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=x$
. The rest is just solving the second order differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

What you cleverly did makes a lot of sense and leads to the solution. Using $x'=y$ gives $x''=y'$. Now, fiffrentiate the first equation
$$2x'-x+y'-2y=0$$ to get $$2x''-x'+y''-2y'=0$$ which rewrite $$2y'-y+y''-2y'=y''-y=0$$ that is to say $$y=c_1 e^t+c_2 e^{-t}$$ Now, use, as you also found, $x=y'$ to get $x$.